# flutter: Make a column layout expand to fill the screen

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout, treeview

This feels like a basic problem and I somehow made it work, but I'm not happy with my solution. So I hope someone can jump in and suggest a more elegant one.

### Goal

I have a column-based layout derived from the [flutter_simple_treeview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_simple_treeview) example. [The google official repo](https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets) has the full source code, and [a web demo](https://flutter_simple_treeview.surge.sh/#/).

My goal is to modify the layout so that

- The 4 buttons can lay as a row at the bottom of the screen.
- The TreeView will fill the rest of the space.
- No wasted screen space except for the padding.

### The result

This is what I've got. The TreeView and the bottom buttons are wrapped in colored containers only for clarity.

[image]

### The code

The page in the above screenshot is rendered with the code below:

lib/trees/controller_usage.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_simple_treeview/flutter_simple_treeview.dart';

class ControllerUsage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ControllerUsageState createState() => _ControllerUsageState();
}

class _ControllerUsageState extends State<ControllerUsage> {
  final Key _key = ValueKey(22);
  final TreeController _controller = TreeController(allNodesExpanded: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 530,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            flex: 2,
            child: SizedBox( // tight constraints
              // height: 450,
              width: 350,
              child: buildTree(),
            ),
          ),
          //TODO:
          // - place a row of btns at the bottom
          // const Spacer(),
          Container(
            color: Colors.amber,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Unfold All"),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    _controller.expandAll();
                  }),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Fold All"),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    _controller.collapseAll();
                  }),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Unfold 22"),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    _controller.expandNode(_key);
                  }),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text("Fold 22"),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    _controller.collapseNode(_key);
                  }),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildTree() {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: TreeView(
          treeController: _controller,
          nodes: [
            TreeNode(content:  const Text("node 11")),
            TreeNode(
              content: const Icon(Icons.audiotrack),
              children: [
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(
                  content: const Text("node 22"),
                  key: _key,
                  children: [
                    TreeNode(
                      content: const Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                TreeNode(
                  content: const Text("node 23"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

lib/main.dart

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

import 'trees/controller_usage.dart';
import 'trees/tree_from_json.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('flutter_simple_treeview Demo'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    "Source Code",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async => await launch(
                      'https://github.com/google/flutter.widgets/tree/master/packages/flutter_simple_treeview/example')),
            ],
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: "Tree Controller Usage"),
                Tab(text: "Tree From JSON"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              buildBodyFrame(ControllerUsage()),
              buildBodyFrame(TreeFromJson()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Adds scrolling and padding to the [content].
  Widget buildBodyFrame(Widget content) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Implementation details and questions

To have the widgets fill the screen, I ended up using a `SizedBox` inside the `SingleChildScrollView` as a constraint. Other failed attempts:

- Placing the `SizedBox` with the same height constraint around the `SingleChildScroolView` gives me a blank screen.
- Placing the `SizedBox` inside the `SingleChildScroolView` without a height constraint gives me a blank screen.
- Placing an `Expanded` inside the `SingleChildScroolView` instead of the `SizedBox` gives me a blank screen as well.

Then I got a bad feeling about that magic nunber height constraint because then I'd have to adapt to different screens this way. I wish I could simply "expand" to the screen size without magic numbers or `MediaQuery`. **Is this possible?**

To make the `TreeView` "push" the button Row to the bottom, I had to use a `Flexible` around the `TreeView`. This feels goofy as well because it seems to break the code symmetry.

Another problem I found with the `SingleChildScrollView`:

As I add more `TreeNode`s to the `TreeView`, I expect that the scroll can work automatically. But in reality, I get the offshoot errors as shown below.

[image]

I'd appreciate it if someone can suggest an improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `buildBodyFrame`, remove `SingleChildScrollView` and add it to `buildTree` then use `LayoutBuilder`, to calculate remain size in column for tree.

App class:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 1,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('flutter_simple_treeview Demo'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  child: const Text(
                    "Source Code",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {}),
            ],
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: "Tree Controller Usage"),
                // Tab(text: "Tree From JSON"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              buildBodyFrame(ControllerUsage()),
              // buildBodyFrame(TreeFromJson()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Adds scrolling and padding to the [content].
  Widget buildBodyFrame(Widget content) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      color: Colors.green,
      child: content,
    );
  }
}
```

ControllerUsage class :

```
class ControllerUsage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ControllerUsageState createState() => _ControllerUsageState();
}

class _ControllerUsageState extends State<ControllerUsage> {
  final Key _key = ValueKey(22);
  final TreeController _controller = TreeController(allNodesExpanded: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Container(
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                width: double.infinity,
                child: buildTree());
          },
        )),
        Container(
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Unfold All"),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _controller.expandAll();
                }),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Fold All"),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _controller.collapseAll();
                }),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Unfold 22"),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _controller.expandNode(_key);
                }),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text("Fold 22"),
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _controller.collapseNode(_key);
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget buildTree() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blueAccent,
        child: TreeView(
          treeController: _controller,
          nodes: [
            TreeNode(content: const Text("node 11")),
            TreeNode(
              content: const Icon(Icons.audiotrack),
              children: [
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(content: const Text("node 21")),
                TreeNode(
                  content: const Text("node 22"),
                  key: _key,
                  children: [
                    TreeNode(
                      content: const Icon(Icons.sentiment_very_satisfied),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                TreeNode(
                  content: const Text("node 23"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That looks great! Question: About the `constraints.maxHeight` under `Column`, is this the max height of its parent `Expanded`? And since Expanded has no max height, then is this the max height of its parent Column? Then how could that be the height of the TreeView, as part of the Column? Do I misunderstand the constraint?

Comment: Also, why should I move the `SingleChildScrollView` down the hierarchy? What does that offer? Is it because `SizedBox` gave a hard constraint so adding nodes will break that constraint illegally, but if it's under the `LayoutBuilder`, then the derived constraint ensures that it scrolls without an issue?

Comment: Glad to hear that. About your question, in column we have two widget,  bottom buttons and layout builder. By wrapping layout builder with expanded we tell flutter to expand as much as possible to fit that column which means fit the tab view, so  constraints.maxHeight  represent the hight.

Comment: when you put your column inside SingleChildScrollView, it means that your column height is unbounded so we can use expanded to get remain height because it is infinity.